# Options appearing in untouched select input

Tags: angular, html-select

**Edit:**
This question has a duplicate: [Select dropdown displays element that is not selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47905849/select-dropdown-displays-element-that-is-not-selected)

In my application there is a select-dropdown which dynamically changes the options it offers based on the value of another input field.

(Basically I could just remove one of the options when the user clicks a button.)

In case the user has not yet selected anything in the dropdown, it should remain empty. But as soon as I programmatically remove one of the options, the first options is displayed as the selected option

**Here is the defective plunkr, showing option"1" when clicking the button:** https://plnkr.co/edit/ayzM2HNtO6Hkkr8jkgVA?p=preview

Now, I did find out what causes this behaviour: Removing the import of *BrowserAnimationsModule* will make the select-dropdown behave normally, without changing its selection when clicking the button:

T**his is the working plunkr:**
https://plnkr.co/edit/dPDpEQm14pWlFNfLe4nP?p=preview

Now my question: Is this a bug? The BrowserAnimationsModule should not cause select-inputs to change their behaviour?

Here is the working sourcecode (BrowserAnimationsModule removed from imports in the module)

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';  // <-- #1 import module

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button type="button" (click)="doFilter();">click me</button>

      <form [formGroup]="myForm">
        <select formControlName="dropdown">
          <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">{{item}}</option>
        </select>

      </form>

    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
    ) {
    this.items = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      dropdown: ''
    });
  }

  private doFilter() {
      this.items = [1,2,3,4,5];
  }

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: It is working properly when i tested in your plunkr. It maybe some browser quirk.. which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome 59

Comment: So am I. Try clearing your browser cache and reloading it?

Comment: actually I tried it at home and at work, on both machines the error occurs

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47905849/select-dropdown-displays-element-that-is-not-selected.