# Select dropdown displays element that is not selected

Tags: angular

So, after migrating my hole project from Angular 2 > Angular 5, I noticed a weird behavior on the `select`.

I have several `select` that call a webservice in order to load their data.

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="viewName">
     <option [ngValue]="null"></option><option *ngFor="let value of viewnames" [ngValue]="value">
          {{value}}
     </option>
</select>
```

When the web service is called for the first time, there is no problem, nothing is selected by default, the select is empty, and the dropdown display the list of elements.

Now when I call the web service for the 2nd time, nothing is selected by default, **but the select displays the first element of the list**, and the dropdown display the list of elements.

I insist on the fact that even though the first element is displayed, it is not selected (the ngModel is empty).

Emptying the list before calling the web service, does fix the issue but since I have more than 100 webservices to check I was wondering if there is not a better way to solve the issue

```
//This fixes the issue
let viewnames = [];
this.service.getViewNames().subscribe(...)
```

Is there a better way to solve the issue?

**EDIT** : After literally hours of debugging, and (thanks to Pierre Mallet) trying to reproduce the bug on StackBlitz, it seems that the issue is cause by `BrowserAnimationsModule`.

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjrg1p)**

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: i try to reproduce your case (mocking service call with observable.of ) but no problem occurs ( https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7hr2de ). I think you should provide more of your code, like this.service.getViewNames() implementation and example of data returned

Comment: displaying the first element of the list is a weird behavior , can you please show more *TS* code ? so we can maybe see the reason of this behavior?

Comment: viewName=null ?

Comment: After HOURS of debugging I finally managed to see where the problem is comming from, I use `@angular/animations` in my project and that's what causing the behavior, I edited my post.

Comment: Upon investigation it seems thats a bug of `BrowserAnimationsModule` : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that this is a bug of `BrowserAnimationsModule` : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18430

If your not using animations you can just remove the module and you should be fine. If you're using them (or use a module that is using them) as simple workaround would be to add `animations: [trigger('',[])]` to your components.

```
@Component({
  animations: [trigger('', [])],
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
```